# Javascript: map an array of items and call function for data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am new to javascript. I have an id, name and time that I am trying to get from my `data` and for each name I am trying to loop through the `data` and call a function from each name. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much!

This is what I have done

```
const data = [
    [
        {
            "id": "14hyzdrdsquo",
            "name": "Ronald",
            "time": '12pm',
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "1f496w43b8yi",
            "name": "Jack",
            "time": '1am',
        },
    ],

]

const getData = (id, name, time) => {
    const ids = [] // desired ['14hyzdrdsquo','1f496w43b8yi']
    const names = []// desired ['Ronald','Jack']
    const times = []// desired ['12pm','1am']
    
    ids.push(id) // should have each id in this array
    names.push(name) // should have each name in this array
    times.push(time) // should have each time in this array

}

var id = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)
data.map(j => j.map(i => getData(id, i.name, i.time)))
```

Comment: please add a complete result, you want.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have added the desired result in the getData function of what I would like to obtain for each array

Answer (score 0):

Using a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, you can loop through your array and group on the keys of each object. Since you have arrays in your outer array, you can use another for loop to loop over those and get each object. Then you can use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to over the keys in your object. For each key, you can check if it exists within `grouped`, and if it does, concatenate the object's value to the grouped array. If it doesn't exist, you can create a new element, and push the value. Once you have grouped everything, you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull out the array values from your object into variables:

```js
const data = [[{ "id": "14hyzdrdsquo", "name": "Ronald", "time": '12pm', }, ], [{ "id": "1f496w43b8yi", "name": "Jack", "time": '1am', }, ],];

const grouped = {};
for(const arr of data) {
  for(const obj of arr) {
    for(const key in obj) {
      grouped[key] = (grouped[key] || []).concat(obj[key]);
    }
  }
}

const {id, name, time} = grouped;
console.log(id);
console.log(name);
console.log(time);
```

The above concept can be achieved with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as well, where the `grouped` array gets built by using the accumulator argument of the reduce method, and each object is iterated using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const data = [[{ "id": "14hyzdrdsquo", "name": "Ronald", "time": '12pm', }, ], [{ "id": "1f496w43b8yi", "name": "Jack", "time": '1am', }, ],];

const grouped = data.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  arr.forEach(obj => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      acc[key] = [...(acc[key] || []), val];
    });
  })
  return acc;
}, {});

const {id, name, time} = grouped;
console.log(id);
console.log(name);
console.log(time);
```

Lastly, if you're happy with doing multiple iterations through your array, you can use [.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to iterate through your array, and for each array, [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the objects inside of that. For each object you can extract the key using destructuring assignment. The result of the inner map is then flattened into the outer resulting array due to `.flatMap()`:

```js
const data = [[{ "id": "14hyzdrdsquo", "name": "Ronald", "time": '12pm', }, ], [{ "id": "1f496w43b8yi", "name": "Jack", "time": '1am', }, ],];


const id = data.flatMap(arr => arr.map(({id}) => id));
const name = data.flatMap(arr => arr.map(({name}) => name));
const time = data.flatMap(arr => arr.map(({time}) => time));
console.log(id);
console.log(name);
console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the double nested array and take the entries of the object and push the values to the same named properties with `'s'`.

Ath the end destructure the objct for single arrays.

```js
const
    data = [[{ id: "14hyzdrdsquo", name: "Ronald", time: '12pm' }], [{ id: "1f496w43b8yi", name: "Jack", time: '1am' }]],
    { ids, names, times } = data.reduce((r, [o]) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (r[k + 's'] ??= []).push(v));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(ids);
console.log(names);
console.log(times);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems is you put

```
   const ids = [] // desired ['14hyzdrdsquo','1f496w43b8yi']
   const names = []// desired ['Ronald','Jack']
   const times = []// desired ['12pm','1am']
```

inside `getData` function. That's mean you created new one arrays time when call `getData`
and for you solution better use .forEach instead of .map.

```
 const data = [
    [
        {
            "id": "14hyzdrdsquo",
            "name": "Ronald",
            "time": '12pm',
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "1f496w43b8yi",
            "name": "Jack",
            "time": '1am',
        },
    ],

]


 const ids = [] // desired ['14hyzdrdsquo','1f496w43b8yi']
 const names = []// desired ['Ronald','Jack']
 const times = []// desired ['12pm','1am']
    

const getData = (id, name, time) => {
   
    ids.push(id) // should have each id in this array
    names.push(name) // should have each name in this array
    times.push(time) // should have each time in this array

}

var id = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)
data.forEach(j => j.forEach(i => getData(id, i.name, i.time)))
console.log(ids)
console.log(names)
console.log(times)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do that using reduce inside each loop so you can have lower complexity.

```js
     const data = [
            [
                {
                    id: '14hyzdrdsquo',
                    name: 'Ronald',
                    time: '12pm',
                },
                {
                    id: '14hyzdrdsquo',
                    name: 'Ronald',
                    time: '12pm',
                },
            ],
            [
                {
                    id: '1f496w43b8yi',
                    name: 'Jack',
                    time: '1am',
                },
                {
                    id: '1f496w43b8yi',
                    name: 'Jack',
                    time: '1am',
                },
            ],
        ];
        
     
          let ids = [];
        let names = [];
        let times = [];
        data.forEach((elem) => {
            const obj = elem.reduce(
                (acc, curr, i) => {
                    acc.ids.push(curr.id);
                    acc.names.push(curr.name);
                    acc.times.push(curr.time);
                    return acc;
                },
                {
                    ids: [],
                    names: [],
                    times: [],
                }
            );
            ids = [...ids, ...obj.ids];
            names = [...names, ...obj.names];
            times = [...times, ...obj.times];
        });
        console.log({
            ids,
            names,
            times,
        });
```